# Automorphisms in unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{D}=\{|z|<1,\ z\in\mathbb{C}\}$. Are there any other automorphisms in $\mathbb{D}$ except the Blaschke factor $\displaystyle B_{a}(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z},\ a\in\mathbb{D}$?

I denote with $\overline{a}$ the complex conjugate of $a$.

Thank you for your time,

Chris

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$f(z) = ze^{i\theta}$ for $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, the rotations are also conformal automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$.

In fact, if you denote $\Psi_a$ for $a \in \mathbb{D}$ as the Blaschke factor above, you can prove that all conformal automorphism are of the form $f(z) = \Psi_a(z)e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: So, the Blaschke factor is just a particular case for $\theta=0$ and all other possible automorphisms of $\mathbb{D}$ are constructed by multiplying the Blaschke factor with some $e^{i\theta}$ and these are the only ones?

Comment: Yes. If I recall the proof has something to do with using the Schwarz Lemma. Look in Stein and Shakarchi _Complex Analysis_ for the proof.

Comment: I think this is in the exercises, not sure which Chapter.

Comment: @ChangweiZhou I believe it is the conformal automorphism chapter. I think it is done in the text where they classify the conformal automorphisms of the disc.